# How can I scrape several pages of a pdf?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, spyder, screen-scraping

My code is like this:

```
df = tabula.read_pdf('test.pdf', pages = ['all'])[0]

df.head()

df.to_excel('test.xlsx')`
```

When I run it, I have just the first page in my Excel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the whole pdf with all pages but you fetch the erst element.

```
df = tabula.read_pdf('test.pdf', pages = ['all'])[0]
                                                 ^^^
```

I think you have to remove that and concat it to get all pages to excel. Something like that:

```
dfs = tabula.read_pdf(self.file, pages='all')
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@dilipjain0504/pdf-tabular-data-extraction-into-excel-with-python-tabula-py-e913f5184819) is a good article how to handle pdfs